# No longer able to call Curl or Ruby in OS X Terminal

Tags: macos, git, node.js, curl, osx-lion

I am running OS X 10.7.3.

I installed Git.  I then git cloned cloned NVM:

```
git clone git://github.com/creationix/nvm.git ~/.nvm
```

Since I git cloned NVM, simple commands such as "curl" and "ruby" are no longer recognized in my terminal.  Did it screw up my globals - and how can I get them back to normal on OS Lion?

My .bash_profile is as follows:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/git/bin
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin"`

or

`export PATH="/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: You're saying that's what I should change my .bash_profile content to?

Answer (score 0):

When you set the PATH you need to append (or sometimes prepend) something to it like this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin
```

By doing just export PATH=/usr/local/git/bin you are wiping out the original setting of PATH and pretty much breaking running things in that window.

You should edit your .bash_profile and reset the PATH to export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin otherwise a lot of things might not work anymore.